# Copy data from one DB to another DB and take backup on Azure using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

We have hosted our database on Azure. 
We have requirement to take specific data from specific tables from source DB, move it to another database along with tables (Destination DB) and then take backup of it.
Is there any way to achieve this task programmatically using c#.

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far? Have you looked into `SqlBulkCopy` or other methods available within C#? Please supply some of your attempt code. This helps other users to know what you haven't tried so that we can better assist.

Comment: Initially when not on azure we used linked servers and openrowset functions and then taking backup of it. But once shifted on Azure, we are able to copy database, can delete non required data but cannot take backup of it.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect your intent, you seem to be more concerned with how to backup the database than how to copy from one database to another.

Comment: i am concerned over both, in SqlBulkCopy case, i wont be able to copy schema, for it Destination DB should be present there. I was wondering if something like `insert into destination.tbl FROM Source.tbl` available.

Comment: This is possible using simple `SqlCommand` objects (if done correctly), however the major prerequisite of the databases either being on the same server or on linked servers needs to be accounted for, also depends on if you're going from a database hosted with Azure to a database SQL Server; there are syntactical differences between the two that cause issues for starters.

Comment: It would be on Same Azure SQL server and the destination DB would be on same server. There is no local server involved.

Comment: will DacServices do trick for me?

Answer (score 0):

There are various approach to replicate data from one db to another. You could use existing SQL plugins or SqlFU plugin to query your data into an object class and than inserting it to your destination DB.

But for backing up to Azure, I think this is dependent to your Azure services that you subscribe.

Comment: We can use SqlBulkCopy to import the selected data but issue will still exist, how to take backup of it and store to AzureBlob Storage.

Comment: Hmm I see, than as mention earlier its based on the Azure services in your Azure Portal. Perhaps this link below could shed some info on it.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/storage-blob-dotnet-getting-started/